# How to change all product inventory options to config settings?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, configuration, inventory

how can i change all products's inventory setting to "config settings"

I want all my product to have same setting for Inventory section which is same as config settings.   After I made a database backup to my new magento, all of my products didn't have any "check" on the "config settings" in "inventory" section.

I wanted set my setting same as config settings which is for

**Manage Stock:**  `Use Config Settings`

**Enable Qty Increments:**  `Use Config Settings`
**Qty Increments:**  `Use Config Settings`

Answer (score 3):

Fastest way to do this is in the backend/PhpMyAdmin via mysql.

**Manage Stock**

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `use_config_manage_stock` = '1'
```

**Enable Qty Increments**

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `use_config_enable_qty_inc` = '1'
```

**Qty Increments**

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `use_config_qty_increments` = '1'
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you! but it does not work.  it keeps on giving me a error.  And on the in product->inventory  nothing has been changed.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column '1' in 'field list'   msg comes out.

Comment: Did you reindex all your tables and flush all cache?

Comment: Yes. I did reindex all my tables but I only refresh the cache instead of flush it.